# How to display alt and title

Tags: fotorama

I need to display the title and the alt of my picture in my fotorama carousel.
I take the alt and the title in the  but when my page is loaded, fotoroma hides (or deletes) the alt and title. I don't know where the option to show my attribute is.

Does anyone know where the function or option for this is?

Thanks

Frink

Comment: You need to share some code to give people something to understand what you're doing.

Comment: How has this not been fixed yet?!

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution for this issue.

In order to show the Alt and Title in image use the image with in DIV.

Use  :

```
<div><img  src="http://www.example.com/image.png" alt="My Alt" title="My Title"/></div>
```

Instead of :

```
<img  src="http://www.example.com/image.png" alt="My Alt" title="My Title"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Fotorama [3.0.8](http://fotoramajs.com) uses the [`alt`](http://fotoramajs.com/customize/#caption) attribute:

```
<div class="fotorama">
    <img src="1.jpg" alt="One">
    <img src="2.jpg" alt="Two">
</div>
```

Enable captions with:

```
<script>
fotoramaDefaults = {
    caption: 'overlay' // or 'simple' or 'none'
}
</script>
```

Fotorama [4.4.8](http://fotorama.io) uses the [`data-caption`](http://fotorama.io/customize/options/#captions-boolean) attribute:

```
<div class="fotorama">
    <img src="1.jpg" data-caption="One">
    <img src="2.jpg" data-caption="Two">
</div>
```

Enable captions with:

```
<script>
fotoramaDefaults = {
    captions: true
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

for use title and alt use this patched fotorama.js

/*!
 * Fotorama 4.6.4 patched alt title | http://fotorama.io/license/
 * https://github.com/artpolikarpov/Fotorama + patch
 */

Replace this

```
f=n(c.width||a.attr("width")),g=n(c.height||a.attr("height"));d.extend(c,{width:f,height:g,thumbratio:S
```

to

```
f=n(c.width||a.attr("width")),g=n(c.height||a.attr("height")),x=a.attr("alt"),y=a.attr("title");;d.extend(c,{width:f,height:g,alt:x,title:y,thumbratio:S
```

and

this

```
t.on("load",q).on("error",o)),m.state="",s.src=w}}})}function Qb
```

to

```
t.on("load",q).on("error",o)),m.state="",s.alt=m.data.hasOwnProperty('alt')?m.data.alt:'',s.title=m.data.hasOwnProperty('title')?m.data.title:'',s.src=w}}})}function Qb
```